# Python (beautiful-soup) returning "none" for existing html while crawling

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, ssl-certificate

i simply want to get the html of search bar of https://www.daraz.com.pk website. i have wrote a code and tried it on "https://www.amazon.com", "https://www.alibaba.com", "https://www.goto.com.pk" and many others, it works fine. but its not working on https://www.daraz.com.pk.

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from urllib import request
    import ssl
    import requests

    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

    html =  urlopen("https://www.daraz.com.pk")
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
    nameList = bsObj.find("input", {"type": "search"})
    print(nameList)
```

it returns **none**, instead it should return :

```
input type="search" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Search in Daraz" class="search-box__input--O34g" tabindex="1" value="" data-spm-anchor-id="a2a0e.home.search.i0.35e34937eWCmbI"
```

i have also tried the similar code on amazon, alibaba and some other sites, which successfully returned their html:

```
     html =  urlopen("https://www.amazon.com")
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
    nameList = bsObj.find("input", {"type": "text"})
    print(nameList)
```

i have also tried it with this way:

```
    bsObj=BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.daraz.com.pk").content, 
    "html.parser")

    nameList = bsObj.find("input", {"type": "search"})
    print(nameList)
```

and this way using selenium:

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.daraz.com.pk")

    time.sleep(2)
    content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
    time.sleep(2)
    officials = soup.find("input", {"type":"search"})
    print(str(officials))
```

but failed.